# Why are the binary files (exe / dll) different between two builds of the exact same version of a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, binaryfiles

Why does rebuilding the exact same version of a C# solution produces different binary files (exe / dll)? Is there a way to avoid this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.5.

**EDIT:**

I actually found a timestamp in the COFF Header of the binary files. Any idea on how to remove it (is this is even possible)?

Thanks

Comment: Auto-increment buildnumber and/or a timestamp somewhere?

Comment: How do you tell they are different? Maybe they contain simple "build time" somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate question, I haven't seen it before posting mine. I edited my question.

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results/